# CodeLite not working with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, codelite

I'm having some troubles to get my CodeLite IDE working with Boost library.

So basically, I've got CodeLite v.6.1.1 and Boost library downloaded from sourceforge. I would love to make it actually working, but I failed to do so using the following concept:

I did create new workspace, than I did go -> **Settings** -> **Build Settings** -> **Compilers** (here I have two compilers, one of which is CodeLite 4.8.1 and the other one is MinGW Code::Blocks, I did select **CodeLite 4.8.1.** -> **Advanced** -> **Global Paths** -> and I did provide two blank lines of Include Path and Libraries Path with the directory of unpacked boost library (Windows 7): **C:\boostlib\boost_1_57_0.**

In this catalog (i.e.: C:\boostlib\boost_1_57_0), I have got all neccesary files, all of them are unzipped and yet I can't get it working.

Besides, I can't click on apply when I'm done with setting path to files containing boost library, all I can do is click ok but once I'm done with this I can't work with libraries from boost.

The following code isn't working:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{

   using namespace boost::lambda;  
   // ERROR MESSAGE: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp, No such file or directory
   typedef std::istream_iterator in;
   std::for_each(in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << ” ” );
   return 0;

}
```

The message I get is:

**boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory**

Is there any chance I can get CodeLite working with boost library or should I simply switch IDE and forget about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track but need to point to the libs and include folders inside the boost directory.

I use the the http://nuwen.net/mingw.html version of mingw as STL (the guy) includes boost as part of his distribution.

So in codeLite I just have to add 
C:\MinGW\lib  to the libraries path
C:\MinGW\include  to the include path